# In Rust, how do I work around a link failiure "/usr/libexec/gcc/avr/ld: cannot find -lstdc++"?

Tags: rust, arduino

I am trying to cross-compile for an Arduino Uno.  I have gotten to the point where I am getting the following error:

```
 $ ~/.cargo/bin/cargo build
   Compiling bacon v0.1.0 (/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/bacon)
warning: cc1plus: warning: '-fPIC' is not supported [-fPIC]
   Compiling rust-arduino-blink-3 v0.1.0 (/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3)
error: linking with `avr-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "avr-gcc" "-mmcu=atmega328p" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/thoth/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2021-01-07-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib" "/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/rust_arduino_blink_3-09a480000c7899fd.panic_halt-0678487765a992dd.panic_halt.ei8zczol-cgu.0.rcgu.o.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/rust_arduino_blink_3-09a480000c7899fd.elf" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-L" "/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/build/bacon-c6b054653910c446/out" "-L" "/home/thoth/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2021-01-07-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/tmp/rustcKtTmC9/libbacon-279c1aaca7a35b3b.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/thoth/src/rust-arduino-blink-3/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-49233f77b92d585e.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lstdc++" "-lgcc"
  = note: /usr/libexec/gcc/avr/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted

error: could not compile `rust-arduino-blink-3`
```

I have tried to run the `avr-gcc` from the command line, and have found that if I remove `-lstdc++` and replace `/tmp/rustcKtTmC9/libbacon-279c1aaca7a35b3b.rlib` with `target/avr-atmega328p/debug/build/bacon-c6b054653910c446/out/libneopixel.a` (because the /tmp/rust* directory is deleted) that the compile succeeds (and I am able to install the `.elf` using `avrdude`).

What is the proper way to adjust the Rust build process so that it will succeed (either removing `-lstdc++` or adding flags that enable it to find the library) ?

Comment: if you cross compile why don't you use `--target` ?

Comment: The --target is provided by .cargo/config.toml .  That just happens to be the idiom provided by the https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template.git template for AVR Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust's `cc` crate includes logic such that if the `cpp` flag is set, it includes `libstdc++`.  It is possible to disable this using  `build.cpp_set_stdlib(None)` .